# Eudyptula Challenge and kernel path

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, eudyptula-challenge

I have decided to take the [Eudyptula Challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/).
After I submitted the first task which is to build a simple "Hello World!" module, I received the following answer.

> Please read the requirements for the Makefile and allow the module to be
>   built against any kernel source tree on the filesystem, not just those
>   kernels that happened to be installed in `/lib/` at some point in time.

The requirements are:

> The Makefile should be able to build the kernel module against the
>   source of the currently-running kernel as well as being able to accept
>   an arbitrary kernel sources directory from an environment variable.

What I am doing is checking whether the environment variable `KERNELRELEASE` is set. If it is I build the module against

```
$(KERNELRELEASE)/build
```

and if it isn't against

```
/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

I can't understand why this does not satisfy the requirements of this task.

Comment: If you are found to have posted your code publicly, or asked for help in
public locations, or copied code from public locations without properly
attributing it, or tried to cheat or fake challenge results in any way,
you will be removed from the challenge instantly. In short, do your own
work, and keep it to yourself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per [Eudyptula challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/) rules, it is prohibited to give you direct solution, so I will try to describe *elements* of answer, so you can come up with solution by yourself. Basically, everything I've written below is described pretty much in [Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html) file (especially in [section 3.1 - Shared Makefile](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html#shared-makefile) ), so I don't think it would be some sort of rules violation. So below is just explanation for what is described in mentioned documentation.

### `KERNELRELEASE` variable

What you are wrong about is thinking that `$(KERNELRELEASE)` is intended for keeping the path to the kernel. What `$(KERNELRELEASE)` variable actually means -- you can find it in [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#kbuild-variables):

> `KERNELRELEASE`

> `$(KERNELRELEASE)` is a single string such as `"2.4.0-pre4"`, suitable
> for constructing installation directory names or showing in
> version strings.  Some arch `Makefiles` use it for this purpose.

The thing is, your `Makefile` is going to be executed 2 times: from **your** `make` command and from **kernel** `Makefile`. And `$(KERNELRELEASE)` can be helpful to figure it out:

1. If this variable is not defined, your `Makefile` is running from your `make` command; at this step you are going to execute kernel's `Makefile` (providing kernel directory using `-C` param). Once you have run `make` for kernel's Makefile (from **inside** of your Makefile), your `Makefile` is going to be executed second time (see next item).
2. If this variable is defined, your `Makefile` is executing from kernel's `Makefile` (which defined this variable and called your `Makefile` back). At this step you can use kernel build system features, like [obj-m](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#loadable-module-goals-obj-m).

### `-C` param

What you really need to do is define some custom variable in your `Makefile` which will hold kernel directory path. You can call it `KDIR` for example. As you know, your kernel sources are located at this path: `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`. Next you can provide this variable to `-C` param (see [man 1 make](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make)) when executing kernel's Makefile.

Next you have to make it possible to pass this variable from outside of your `Makefile`. To do so, one can use [conditional variable assignment operator](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html):

```
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

This way if you pass `KDIR` variable to your Makefile, like this:

```
$ make KDIR=bla-bla-bla
```

the `KDIR` variable will have the value you passed. Otherwise it will contain default value, which is `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`.