# How to compile a Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world module following this [guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN121) and I'm confused about what the `Makefile` is actually doing.

Here it is:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I understand that when I type the `make` command it will run the `all` recipe which runs `make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules`.  So now it runs the Makefile found at the path given after the `-C` flag, but what does the `M=$(PWD) modules` do?

Comment: ok thank you, but what does `M=$(PWD) modules`

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031161/eudyptula-challenge-and-kernel-path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a breakdown:

1. `obj-m`: specifies object files which are built as loadable kernel modules.
2. `all` and `clean`: If you run `make` by default it will run the first target, which is `all`. But we can use `make all` and `make clean` too: it will run only those specific targets.

   For example:

   ```bash
   make all
   # Will run: make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

   make clean
   # Will run: make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
   ```
3. `uname -r`: get version information about the current kernel.

   Example: for me, the output is `4.6.0-rc1`.
4. Option `-C dir`: change to directory `dir` before reading the makefiles in there.

   Example:

   ```bash
   make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
   # Will translate to: make -C /lib/modules/4.6.0-rc1/build
   # And execute the Makefile at /lib/modules/4.6.0-rc1/build/Makefile
   ```
5. `$(PWD)`: get the path of your current directory.

Now you want to create your loadable module by using:

```bash
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Your source code needs a specific environment to be compiled. That's why we have to use the `-C` option to change build directory. Which have all needed definitions, header file, macros etc. Now after changing to the build directory you tell the kernel Makefile where your module is located using `M=$(PWD)`.

Comment: Actually, if you run ̀make`, by default it will run the first defined target, unless a variable named .DEFAULT_GOAL is defined to the name of another target.

Answer (score 5):

To compile kernel module, the `make` command you normally need is in this form:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-70-generic/build M=/home/test/ldd3/hello modules
```

in which, `-C` means switching to another path.

```
/lib/modules/3.16.0-70-generic/
```

is the path to the kernel in used, and

```
/home/test/ldd3/hello
```

is where the source of your module resides.

> what does the M=$(PWD) modules do?

So as I said `M=$(PWD)` is simply a shell variable that stores the current path to your kernel module. `make` needs to store this as it switches to the kernel build path.

Comment: I downloaded my device kernel source code from http://openlinux.amlogic.com:8000/download/ARM/kernel/?C=M;O=D , but there is no build folder!