# Is it possible to compile a custom Linux kernel driver without compiling the Linux kernel itself?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm just curious if it is possible to compile a Linux kernel driver (* .ko binary) with only Linux kernel sources?
Is it inevitable to have a compiled Linux kernel to compile a Linux kernel driver?

Comment: You can use the [KBuild](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) method as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979628/14393739

Comment: Yes, it’s quite possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found /lib/modules/ in Linux Kernel source tree. Let me clarify that I need to cross-compile .ko module. It is designed for another kernel/architecture (not for the host).

Comment: You forget to mention the person for whom you wrote your comment. Tag person e.g. like this @RachidK.

Comment: @NK-cell Actually, I replied to both commentators :)

Comment: But they actually didn't know about that :)